# Wordpress WP_Query 'orderby' not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

My query is not ordering my posts using the `orderby` parameter.

A little background:

I'm within a foreach statement that loops through a custom taxonomy for "category" IDs. while in that foreach statement, I am attempting to invoke a new WP_Query getting posts from each "category" of that foreach loop. My args array is as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'wpsc_product_category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $cat_id,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'series',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $series_name
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

`$cat_id` and `$series_name` are both arrays from my custom taxonomies in this post_type.

`orderby` and `order` are not working at all and I cannot figure this out why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have checked your code on my test blog. And it works as expected. So parameters

```
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'DESC'
```

you have set correctly.

In this situation you can check SQL request.

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($query->request);
```

Comment: Agreed. Orderby parameters seem to be correct on my end. I would change 'showposts' to 'posts_per_page' as the showposts parameter was deprecated. The only other thing I would try would be to hardcode each term as its own query parameter (I've had trouble with multiple terms in the past) and set 'relation' to 'AND'.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I did run the var_dump to output the SQL request and it seems that my orderby and order parameters are not even registering. Those two params are still both set to the default values or menu_order and DESC no matter what I change them to. I even tried using a custom field (meta_key and meta_value combo) and those two parameters will not accept the change.

Comment: also, here is the output: GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC

Comment: Try to disable `tax_query` param. Also it is possible that some hooks changing you query. In this case, disable all plugins and run the code from the dafault theme.

Comment: Thanks for helping out with this one. I think I might just have to scrap this query all together and approach it from a different standpoint. The var_dump did give me a better insight into which parts of my query are functioning properly.

Comment: If you add `remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');` before running `new WP_Query` that will sometimes fix the ordering problems.

Comment: @DavidYeiser Care to explain?

Comment: It’s a hard reset of sorts, from what I understand some plugins will affect ordering inadvertently.

Comment: @DavidYeiser Yep, I had a plugin which overwrote my orderby parameter. `var_dump($query->request);` helped expose that.

Comment: @DavidYeiser Thank you :)

Comment: `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` might also help.